# Collapse and expand a view in a tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, constraints

I want to expand and collapse a view in a tableView. Watched this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVlNl4JDzL4

ishidden = true didn't work because the height is still there

```
  func expandCollapse(sender:UIButton) {

    let collapseImage = UIImage(named: "collapse")
    let expandImage = UIImage(named: "expand")

    let row = sender.tag
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)

    let cell = self.table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ArchiveViewCell


    if (sender.currentImage == UIImage(named: "expand")) {
        sender.setImage(collapseImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        cell.moreViewHeight.priority = 1
        cell.moreViewHeight.constant = 0

        cell.moreView.layoutIfNeeded()

    } else {
        sender.setImage(expandImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        cell.moreViewHeight.priority = 999
        cell.moreView.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
```

Comment: In your else block, have you tried changing the `cell.moreViewHeight.constant` back to the view's original height rather than just changing the priority?

Comment: But the original height is not always the same, it's depending on the content